# Ansible :: advanced nested looping

Tags: ansible

I have to process output from CloudFormation `Outputs` that is:

#### Ansible code that produces this output:

```
- debug: 
  var: stack.stack_outputs
```

#### Output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
  "stack.stack_outputs": {
    "Roles": "webserver balancer dbserver",
    "dbserver": "54.0.1.1 54.0.1.2",
    "balancer": "54.0.2.3",
    "webserver": "54.0.2.5 54.0.2.7 54.0.3.1"
}}
```

---

With that, I want to create 3 (dynamic number!) groups named accordingly filled with appropriate IPs.

## Ansible code that I want to HELP WITH:

```
- name: fill roles with proper hosts
  local_action: add_host hostname={{item}} groupname={{role}}
  with_whatever: ?...?
```

#### In pseudo ansible python it would look like this:

```
for role in stack.stack_outputs.Roles.split():                           # Python
  for ip in stack.stack_outputs[role].split():                           # Python
    local_action: add_host hostname={{ip}} groupname={{role}}            # Ansible
```

---

Note:

The way to do it for these three roles *statically* is obviously:

```
- name: fill role WEBSERVER
  local_action: add_host hostname={{item}} groupname=webserver
  with_items: stack.stack_outputs.webserver.split()
- name: fill role DBSERVER
  local_action: add_host hostname={{item}} groupname=dbserver
  with_items: stack.stack_outputs.dbserver.split()
- name: fill role BALANCER
  local_action: add_host hostname={{item}} groupname=balancer
  with_items: stack.stack_outputs.balancer.split()
```

I want to do it ***dynamically***, is it even possible in Ansible?
Yes, I can use `shell module` to hack it putting everything in temporary file and then looping over that; but is there a better solution?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388264/ansible-custom-nested-looping

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using nested loops and includes, example of working script `test.yml`:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
  - stack:
      stack_outputs:
        Roles: "webserver balancer dbserver"
        dbserver: "54.0.1.1 54.0.1.2"
        balancer: "54.0.2.3"
        webserver: "54.0.2.5 54.0.2.7 54.0.3.1"

  tasks:
  - debug: var=stack.stack_outputs

  - include: dynamic.yml
      host_group={{ item.key }}
      group_ips={{ item.value }}
    with_dict: "{{ stack.stack_outputs }}"
```

`dynamic.yml`:

```
---
- debug:
    msg="Group is {{ host_group }} and ip is {{ item2 }}"
  when: item2|ipaddr
  with_items: "{{ group_ips.split() }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: item2
```

Example of running using `ansible-playbook 2.1.2.0`:

```
ansible-playbook test.yml 
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available


PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "stack.stack_outputs": {
        "Roles": "webserver balancer dbserver", 
        "balancer": "54.0.2.3", 
        "dbserver": "54.0.1.1 54.0.1.2", 
        "webserver": "54.0.2.5 54.0.2.7 54.0.3.1"
    }
}

TASK [include] *****************************************************************
included: /home/say/tmp/ansible/dynamic.yml for localhost
included: /home/say/tmp/ansible/dynamic.yml for localhost
included: /home/say/tmp/ansible/dynamic.yml for localhost
included: /home/say/tmp/ansible/dynamic.yml for localhost

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "item_foo": "54.0.2.5", 
    "msg": "Group is webserver and ip is 54.0.2.5"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "item_foo": "54.0.2.7", 
    "msg": "Group is webserver and ip is 54.0.2.7"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "item_foo": "54.0.3.1", 
    "msg": "Group is webserver and ip is 54.0.3.1"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "item_foo": "54.0.2.3", 
    "msg": "Group is balancer and ip is 54.0.2.3"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=None) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=None) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=None) 

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "item_foo": "54.0.1.1", 
    "msg": "Group is dbserver and ip is 54.0.1.1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "item_foo": "54.0.1.2", 
    "msg": "Group is dbserver and ip is 54.0.1.2"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=9    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

You need [Ansible 2.1 or above](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#loop-control) to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Logic that complicated shouldn't exist in a playbook or task list. Consider using [dynamic inventories](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_inventory.html), so you can write a script that returns JSON complete with group membership information. If you really want to handle the data munging in a playbook, you can use a [custom filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#filter-plugins), which still cleans up the playbook significantly.